# "-1.#IND" returned on 64-bit Windows (C++) with fmod operation when denominator is not 0

Tags: floating-point, release, modulus

When performing the below operation:
float remainder_fl = fmod (float(a), float(b));

The "remainder_fl" is set to "-1.#IND", when a = 0 and b = 300. This happens only on with a Windows release 64-bit DLL. With a debug 64-bit DLL, and with Windows 32-bit release and debug DLLS, this issue is not seen at all.

If anyone has any suggestions or pointers on why this might be happening, I would highly appreciate it.

Thank you,
Ash

Machine configuration
64-bit Windows 2008 Std Server, Optimized release DLL.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why this would happen, but it's clearly a bug.  Have you reported it to Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it *may* be a bug but, since it doesn't seem to happen in the latest Visual Studio and a complete program exhibiting the behaviour was not actually provided, it's hard to tell. I used this, based on a reasonable reading of the question:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    double a = 0, b = 300;
    float rem = fmod(float(a), float(b));
    std::cout << rem << "\n";
}
```

I do know that early version of `fmod` had certain problems with returning indeterminate values such as with [this bug report](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/982107/fix-the-fmod-function-returns-an-indeterminate-ind-value-instead-of-th). I'd also be wary of possible problems with casting to and from `float` types, errors could be introduced there.

Bottom line, check your code against the *current* version of Visual Studio and, if the problem still exists, raise a bug report to Microsoft.